# Need help about @Get @Post @Put @Delete in Restful webservice

Tags: sql, web-services, rest, jersey, http-protocols

I need your help and advice. This is my first project in jersey. I don't know much about this topic. I'm still learning. I created my school project. But I have some problems on the web service side. Firstly I should explain my project. I have got 3 tables in my database. ***Movie,User,Ratings***
Here my Movie table columns. I will ask you some  points about Description column of the Movie table. I will use these methods to these columns.
Movie= **Description** (get,put,post and delete) I have to use all methods in this page. 
                 **movieTitle** (get)
                 **pictureURL** (get,put)
                 **generalRating** (get,post)

I built my Description page. But I'm not sure if its working or not .(My database is not ready to check them). Here is my page. I wrote this page, looking at the example pages. Can u help me to find the problems and errors. I just want to do simple methods *get*(just reading data), *post*(update existing data), *put*(create new data), *delete*(delete specific data) these things.What should I do now, is my code okay or do you have alternative advice? :( I need your help guys ty

```
package com.vogella.jersey.first;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.*;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.FormParam;
import javax.ws.rs.OPTIONS;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;




@Path("/Movie/Description")
public class Description {

    private Moviedao moviedao = new Moviedao();

@GET
@Path("/Description/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public Description getDescriptionID(@PathParam("sample6") string sample6){
        return moviedao.getDescriptionID(id);
}

@POST
@Path("/Description/")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public void updateDescription(@PathParam("sampleID")int sampleID,
        @PathParam("sample2Description")string sample2Description) 
        throws IOException  {
          Description description = new Description (sampleID, sample2Description);
          int result = moviedao.updateDescription(description);
          if(result == 1){
             return SUCCESS_RESULT;
          }
          return FAILURE_RESULT;
}

@PUT
@Path("/Description")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String createUser(@FormParam("sample8ID") int sample8ID,
   @FormParam("sample8Description") String sample8Description,
   @Context HttpServletResponse servletResponse) throws IOException{
   Description description = new Description (sample8ID, sample8Description);
   int result = movidao.addDescription(description);
   if(result == 1){
      return SUCCESS_RESULT;
   }
   return FAILURE_RESULT;
}

@DELETE
@Path("/Description/{descriptionID}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String deleteUser(@PathParam("descriptionID") int descriptionID){
   int result = moviedao.deleteDescription(descriptionID);
   if(result == 1){
      return SUCCESS_RESULT;
   }
   return FAILURE_RESULT;
}

@OPTIONS
@Path("/Description")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String getSupportedOperations(){
   return "<operations>GET, PUT, POST, DELETE</operations>";
}


}
```

Comment: So what are you exactly asking?

Comment: "Can u help me to find the problems and errors..." This is a pretty broad question. Would you be able to ask something more specific?

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to do simple methods get(just reading data), <strike>post(update
>   existing data), put(create new data)</strike>, delete(delete specific data)
>   these things

**POST** should be used to create resources and **PUT** should be used to update resources.

Your class already has webservice path **/Movie/Description**, so there is no need to repeat word **Description** in the methods.

Also, I would recommend keep path names in lower case e.g. /movie/description